# The complex will include facilities for the __ of liquefied natural gas

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> The future LNG complex, situated near the ABC gas condensate field, will include facilities for the ___ of liquefied natural gas.

I wonder what would be the proper catch-all term describing facilities used in the "dispatching" of LNG produced at an LNG plant to customers. These facilities might include facilities for the loading of railway tankers, tanker trucks and even LNG carrier ships. I mean tank truck loading racks, railcar loading facilities, all kind of equipment used to pump the gas to a nearby port terminal, facilities inside the terminal, specialized railroad tracks etc.

In Russian, we have the catch-all expression "мощности по отгрузке" (capacities/facilities for the shipping-off), but I guess that "*shipping-off facilities*" would look strange in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Shipping* facilities will do just fine by itself: in this sort of context we don't contrast  *shipping out* with *shipping in* but *shipping* with *receiving*.

And there's no need for *the ... of*: *facilities for shipping LNG*, or perhaps ***the*** LNG, since it appears that what is to be shipped is ***the*** LNG produced at the site, and presumably you have already mentioned that production.

Answer (score 1):

*Distribution* would work.  Production and distribution [commonly appear together](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22production%20and%20distribution%20of%20natural%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl).